# How to update state object in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

How to update state object in useEffect

Hi All,

In my React app I am calling an online service in order to get some WIFI information. Eventually, I would like to show\render the information of the wifiData to the user.

```
const [macAddress, setMacAddress] = useState('');
const [wifiData, setwifiData] = useState({});

const axios = require("axios");
const ClientOAuth2 = require('client-oauth2')
const clientAuth = new ClientOAuth2({
    accessTokenUri: 'https:....',
    clientId: '....',
    clientSecret: '....',
    scopes: ['....']
})

const wifiService = useCallback(() => {
    clientAuth.credentials.getToken().then(function (user) {
        if (user.accessToken) {
            axios({
                method: "post",
                url: "....access_token=" + user.accessToken,
                data: {
                   ....,
                },
            }).then(function (response) {
                // setwifiData ??
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    })
}, [axios, clientAuth.credentials, macAddress])

useEffect(() => {
    if (!openDrawer && macAddress !== "") {
        wifiService();
       // setwifiData ??
    }
}, [wifiService, clientAuth.credentials, openDrawer, macAddress]);

return (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
     // render wifiData
)
```

How can I store the response data in wifiData ?

What is the proper way to deal with this type of scenario? I couldn’t figure it out.

Appreciate the help

Thank you

Comment: setState is the possible method to update/set the state. Did you mean something else?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. When using set state inside the callback it will create an infinity loop.

Comment: Having wifiService as a useEffect trigger is probably causing this.

Comment: Infinite loops from setting state in useEffect typically come from a useEffect trigger

Answer (score 1):

Set the state inside wifiService():

```
const wifiService = useCallback(() => {
    clientAuth.credentials.getToken().then(function (user) {
        if (user.accessToken) {
            axios({
                method: "post",
                url: "....access_token=" + user.accessToken,
                data: {
                   ....,
                },
            }).then(function (response) {
                // ** put response in correct format here if you need to
                setwifiData(response)
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    })
}, [axios, clientAuth.credentials, macAddress])
```

Remove wifiService from useEffect triggers to prevent infinite loop:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!openDrawer && macAddress !== "") {
        wifiService();
    }
}, [clientAuth.credentials, openDrawer, macAddress]);
```

Comment: I think you'd also need to add a `&& !wifiData` to the conditional otherwise once the state is set this will still be called infinitely

Comment: I was thinking he may need to set wifiData more than once but if not then this is a good idea.

Comment: yeah that would only work once, otherwise there would need to be another break condition added

Comment: But, the React Community always recommend to put any methods you invoke inside the useEffect in dependency array. Otherwise it can produce bugs. See some examples here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: True. You just need to find out which one is causing the infinite re-render because setting state in useEffect is very common and itself should not be causing the infinite loop.

Comment: The problem might be with clientAuth.credentials since you are fetching its token inside wifiService and also have it triggering useEffect

Comment: @Mateen In the documentation under `If for some reason you can’t move a function inside an effect, there are a few more options` is an example that shows how you can savely define the function outside of the effect using `useCallback`

Comment: I didn't say that you can't a define a function outside the useEffect, please read my comment again.

Comment: @Mateen read the part of the docs that HMR is referring to and you will see what he is talking about. The point is that it is safe to leave the function out of the dependency array if it is wrapped in a callback like you have done here

Comment: Touche. Did you figure out what is causing the infinite loop?

Comment: @GrantSingleton did see that they put `fetchProduct` in their dependency array though it was created by `useCallback`? And, they also give note below the code.

Comment: Yes I saw that, it says that the dependencies of the callback will trigger a refetch. Which means that one of the dependencies in the callback may be causing the loop

Comment: Do all these need to be here? ```[axios, clientAuth.credentials, macAddress]```

Comment: Thank you all. Appreciate the suggestions.